# Malware question

Tags: malware

A site hosting drive-by malware is configured with a domain name very similar to that of a major social networking website. What is the name of this type of attack?

Comment: Phishing

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5twFT.gif

Comment: [Homograph](https://www.welivesecurity.com/2017/07/27/homograph-attacks-see-to-believe/) attacks are without a doubt the sneakiest types of attacks fitting this description that I've seen, but can't say for certain what this is as it fits many profiles.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a phishing campaign. Tricking user to click because of similar, legit-looking site name is used in order to spread various malware.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Typosquatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like many things in play here.

Drive by downloads are usually linked to you visiting a legit site but then a malicious ad (malvertisement) on that site kicks off a download of some malware (perhaps faking an adobe flash update , etc).

They may make the download site look similar to a legit site by doing many things such as typosquatting (playing on common misspellings ... although typosquatting is more commonly used to prey on victims typing into the url bar and not related to drive by downloads), or perhaps homogenous attacks where they take Unicode characters from different languages that look similar to the real character , or perhaps doppelgänger attacks that have the same spelling but are missing the period between the subdomain and primary domain , or several other variations like just adding prefixes or postfix words to the domain, etc